# Get announce request in Rtsp-Server Gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, rtsp-client

I am using rtsp-server module in GStreamer to save in file a stream received from a client with the RECORD RTSP property.

In the server I am using the signal "media_configure" to modify the element "filesink" adding the property "location" and setting the new name file.

I want that name file is setting from client, in the ANNOUNCE message for example, but I don't know the way.

Any solution??

Thank you very much!!

Comment: just to clarify - you are recording stream on server-side into file and you want for client to be able to set the file name through ANNOUNCE message - that is control server recording from client-side?

Comment: Yes, that is. Thanks.